# Hadoop: Can files be created without overwriting by appending content to the end of the name?

Tags: hadoop

So in a lot of cases, when you add a file to a directory where a file with the same name already exists, it'll append something to the end of it. For example, a unique, incrementing number.

So, let's say the Hadoop system I'm connecting to has a folder called "/input", and there's already a file there called "sample.txt". So the full path would be "/input/sample.txt". If I tried to create a new file with the path "/input/sample.txt", it would save it as "/input/sample1.txt", or something like that. And then there would be two files in that directory, sample.txt and sample1.txt.

I'm new to Hadoop, my company has me building an interface that will allow our application to connect to Hadoop systems. I've got some simple client code working nicely, but I don't see anything in the API about how to do this. It's a behavior that other components of our product have, and while it's not necessary, I would like to be able to provide it for consistency's sake.

Thanks in advance.

PS. The client code I'm working on is in Java and uses Apache's Hadoop Client library.

Comment: How about using a time-stamp? For example `/input/sample-1462905645.txt` for a file created at Tue, 10 May 2016 18:40:45 GMT. This way you need not keep track of the previous file names and the files would have unique names.

Comment: Wish you had answered in the answer question section, I would've totally marked this as the best answer. Avoids messy extensive iteration while achieving the result, it's so simple I can't believe I didn't think of it. Love it.

Comment: Thanks. You could still mark the comment as helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Use FileSystem exists API and change the file to your needs increment or whatever.
sample java code todo that

```
Configuration conf = new Configuration();
conf.set("fs.default.name", "hdfs://namenode:9000");
FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(conf);
Path path = new Path("/input/sample.txt");
if(fs.exists(path)) ....
```

https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.6.1/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileSystem.html